# Filter on a mongodb keys in aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a document like below

```
{
  "name" :{
  "English": "AA",
  "Bengali": "BB",
  "Gujarati": "CC",
  "Hindi": "DD"} 
}
```

can I filter it based on the keys e.g. need to filter only on 'English' and 'Hindi' so the output should be

```
{
  "name" :{
  "English": "AA",
  "Hindi": "DD"} 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to first turn the object into an array of key-value pairs `[{ "k": "Bengali", "v": "BB" }, { "k": "English", "v": "AA" }...]` using `$objectToArray`

Then call `$filter` on the array and take only the ones you need

Finally, convert that array back to an object using `$arrayToObject`

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      name: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $filter: {
            input: { $objectToArray: "$name" },
            cond: { $in: [ "$$this.k", [ "English", "Hindi" ] ] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/H1xeqa4FnGP)

Answer (score 3):

The simple option is to check for key existence and project only the necessary keys :

```
db.collection.find({
"$and": [
 {
   "name.Hindi": {
     "$exists": true
   }
  },
  {
   "name.English": {
     "$exists": true
   }
 }
]
},
{
name: {
 "English": 1,
 "Hindi": 1
 }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UIoXtROUzI2)

But the better option if you are going to use this filter often is to modify the keys to values as follow:

```
[
  {
  "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
   "name": [
    {key:"Bengali" , value:"BB"},
    {key:"English" , value:"AA"},
    {key:"Gujarati", value:"CC"},
    {key:"Hindi",  value:"DD" }
  ]
 }
]
```

where you can do something faster like:

```
   db.collection.find({
  "name.key": {
  $in: [
  "English",
  "Hindi"
  ]
  }
 },
 {
 name: {
  $filter: {
  input: "$name",
  as: "item",
  cond: {
    $in: [
      "$$item.key",
      [
        "English",
        "Hindi"
       ]
      ]
     }
   }
  }
 })
```

Assuming you create in advance an index on the "name.key" field.

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LQHBUkp4pa8)